# Oracle procedure or function that returns a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can i make a procedure or function that returns a SELECT's resultset just like as i make a SELECT directly?

Comment: Do some research on pipelined functions, have a go and post back any issues.

Comment: Is it possible to use some kind of dynamic table type? I want to set different SELECTs for input of this function.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For,

1. Function  : Create a `pipelined` function and use it as table function.

Example :

```
-- Create the types to support the table function.
DROP TYPE t_tf_tab;
DROP TYPE t_tf_row;

CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function itself.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_rows IN NUMBER) RETURN t_tf_tab AS
  l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_rows LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := t_tf_row(i, 'Description for ' || i);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN l_tab;
END;
/

-- Test it.
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_tf(10))
ORDER BY id DESC;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 Description for 10
         9 Description for 9
         8 Description for 8
         7 Description for 7
         6 Description for 6
         5 Description for 5
         4 Description for 4
         3 Description for 3
         2 Description for 2
         1 Description for 1

10 rows selected.
```

[Example Source](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php)

2. Procedure : `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Assuming your Oracle version supports `pipeline` functions and `sys_refcursor`.